# How to concatenate 2 one-dimensional arrays into 1 two-dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to do the following:

```
var arrayA = new Array;
var arrayB = new Array;
var arrayC = new Array;

arrayA = [["one", "two", "three"]];
arrayB = [["four", "five", "six"]];
```

so that I could get

```
arrayC = [["one", "two", "three"], ["four", "five", "six"]];
```

How would I accomplish it?

Comment: Your title says you're combining 1-dimension arrays. But `arrayA` and `arrayB` are 2-dimensional. Did you really mean to put two sets of `[]` around them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a new array that has the other arrays as elements.

```
var arrayC = [arrayA[0], arrayB[0]];
```

BTW, there's no point in initializing the variables to `new Array` if you're just going to assign a different array to them.

Comment: @Pang I didn't notice that his original `arrayA` and `arrayB` are 2-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that

```
arrayC = arrayA.concat(arrayB)
```

Comment: No this would make a one dimentional array. I want a two dimentional array.

Comment: @xxAkuma Did you try it?

Comment: @xxAkuma This works because your original arrays are 2-dimensional, so the result is also 2-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of ways to do this including some that have already been covered.

For instance another approach is to use [`Array.of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) to simply create a new array from a list of arguments;

```js
var arrayA = [["one", "two", "three"]];
var arrayB = [["four", "five", "six"]];
var arrayC = Array.of(arrayA[0], arrayB[0]);

// for display only
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arrayC) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Browser compatibility table might be needed on this one as it is not widely supported yet

Comment: @axelduch Agreed, but as noted it was only to further show there are a lot of ways of approaching this. :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm happy you added this one, I learned something from it as I did not know about this method. I just looked at mdn and thought it could be helpful if people want to copy/paste and expect it to work in all cases

Comment: @axelduch Glad to hear it expanded your knowledge. Presenting a new approach was my main goal as your answer is the obvious approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just push them.

```
arrayC.push(arrayA)
arrayC.push(arrayB)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var arrayC = arrayA.concat()
arrayB.forEach(function(ele,index){
    arrayC.push(ele)
})
```

Is this you want?

Comment: what is the problem?